# How to clone HP-UX server to another fresh server

Tags: hp-ux, cloning

I have a HP-UX box and i want to clone the same to other server. Lets assume HP-UX(A) and other server(B)

```
<SERVER_NAME> $ uname -a
HP-UX <SERVER_NAME> B.11.23 U 9000/800 1544735064 unlimited-user license
```

And "A" is a production box, how do we build a test-environment of same configuration and applications as in that of HP-UX box?

Like, Is there any way to take a live clone of A to B?

Any advise on this?

Comment: 1) use ignite to make a bootable backup, 2) boot second box using ignite, you will have a screen to change IP. this can be done either on lan or on tape, note that former method need skill and later hardware.

Comment: @Archemar You mean using ignite needs skills right? And I have a small query, will it exactly replicate like what all applications are running in this server with its directory structure,

Would you like to recommend me any tutorial page on how to do that?

Comment: Try this manual: http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=4077173&docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c01942668

Comment: And be careful to not violate any license to use for HP-UX Operating Environments. Call your HPE support in case of doubt

Comment: @manolonte that sounds great, thanks for the document, the same ways is there any thing to clone `Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 5)`

Comment: For RedHat I have used Mondo Rescue, similar in concept to Ignite in HP-UX.

Comment: @manolonte so, what i understood is, using Mondo Rescue we can clone the presently active RedHat VM into a new VM with all its applications and all the packages installed and running into the new VM?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. DRD (AKA HP Dynamic Root Disk). You can clone live OS to new disk and then move it to new server. Also you will be able to mount cloned disk, and, for example, edit network setting (like hostname and IP address).
2. Or, as already mentioned - Ignite. This is kinda harder and requires more actions (e.g. you will need to configure Ignite server).

So, if you can physically move HDD from one server to another or you have SAN disks, then the first option is preferable.